# Combine VLOOKUP and IF formulas

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have the following two formulas. I want to have one formula for one column instead of using two.

```
=VLOOKUP(A2,eodcpos!B:I,8,FALSE
=IF(U2="Long","B","S")
```

I use the first one to bring in the value to my sheet in order to do the `IF`, but I would prefer to do it all with one formula.

Comment: So the Vlookup is in U2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you just want to replace the `U2` in the second with the first:

```
=IF(VLOOKUP(A2,eodcpos!B:I,8,FALSE)="Long","B","S")
```